# $\mathrm{E}\left[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'\right]$ and proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{k}$. I read that $\mathrm{E}\left[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'\right]$ has full rank if and only if there exists no proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ having probability 1 under $F_{\mathbf{x}}$. Could someone please explain why it is true (or point to any reference/proof)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "only if" direction, let $\mathbf v$ be a non-zero element of $U^\perp$ for some proper subspace $U \subset \Bbb R^k$ that contains $\mathbf x$ with probability $1$. Show that
$$
\mathbf v'\,\mathbb E[\mathbf x\mathbf x']\,\mathbf v = 0.
$$
Because $\mathbb E[\mathbf x\mathbf x']$ is positive semidefinite, this implies that $\mathbb E[\mathbf x\mathbf x']$ fails to be full rank.

Conversely, if $\mathbb E[\mathbf x\mathbf x']$ is not full rank, then there is a non-zero vector $\mathbf v$ for which $\mathbf v'\,\mathbb E[\mathbf x\mathbf x']\,\mathbf v = 0$, and it follows that $\mathbf x' \mathbf v = 0$ with probability $1$, which means that $\mathbf x$ is an element of the subspace $U = \mathbf v^{\perp}$ with probability $1$.